# Overload jQuery Colorbox Method?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, overloading

There is a method in colorbox JS file:

```
publicMethod.position = function (speed, loadedCallback) {
        var
        animate_speed,
        // keeps the top and left positions within the browser's viewport.
        posTop = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight, 0) / 2 + $window.scrollTop(),
        posLeft = Math.max($window.width() - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth, 0) / 2 + $window.scrollLeft();

        ...more code...
};
```

I want to change the posTop and posLeft variables inside the method. How can I change those variables without editing the core file?

**Edit:**

I tried adding the function to my own scripts like:

```
$.fn.colorbox.position = function (speed, loadedCallback) {
    ...
};
```

and also:

```
var originalMethod = $.fn.colorbox.position;

$.fn.colorbox.position = function (speed, loadedCallback) {
    ...
    return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

None of my changes are working though. If I also `alert($.fn.colorbox.position);` it also shows my changes. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Weird, if I try doing the same thing with another plugin it works, but for colorbox it doesn't. Could it be due to the "publicMethod"?

Answer (score 0):

From my basic understanding, there isn't really overloading as JavaScript doesn't have the notion of inheritance.  You can overwrite a function as long as the second definition appears after the first in the order the page is loaded.  That is to say, lower down in the HTML.

I think you'll have to copy paste an overwrite the function...

Comment: I tried that already (it's displayed after the original), it didn't work. Is there anything additional you'd need to do?